# Sprite Kit restarting the last level

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I have a game in which I have different levels as different SKScenes (LevelOne, LevelTwo etc...)

When you fail the level, i use presentScene: to show the Game Over menu, which is an SKScene and has a button called restart level.

The problem I have is I don't know how to present the failed level as a scene because I don't know how I can send the failed level's data to the game over scene.

A solution I came up with (since there are 50+ levels) is to rewind back to the scene where I had the transition, but I don't know how to do that.

To give an example : I am on level 8. I failed.

```
 GameOver *gameOver = [[GameOver alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOver transition:transition];
```

I used this method to present the GameOver scene. I have a button called restart in game over scene, which performs with selector the following method

```
-(void)restartLevel{

      LevelEight *newScene = [[LevelEight alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2];
    [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
}
```

The problem is that code needs to be generated when we fail at level 8, so i need a mechanism to send that level data.

I thought of using the self.scene.userData and it's objectForKey: method but I don't know how to apply it to this situation.

Comment: the core problem here is creating a subclass for each level. Instead you should gave a level class that performs anything level-specific based on the current level number which you xan make globally available.

Comment: `scene.userData = @{@"level": @8};`? Won't that be enough?

Comment: I ended up using duci9y 's suggestion. LearnCocos2D, unfortunately the levels are very distinct in this game, so each level had to be another scene although the code is very modular.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a solution that might help you, send your level number to GameOver scene class by this way:

```
GameOver *gameOver = [[GameOver alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size levelNumber:currentLevelNumber];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOver transition:transition];
```

and in GameOver scene write a switch statement to check level number that you passed (currentLevelNumber):

```
switch (currentLevelNumber) {
    case 1:
        LevelOne *newScene = [[Levelone alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2];
        [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
        break;
    case 2:
        LevelTwo *newScene = [[LevelTwo alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2];
        [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
        break;
```

kolay gelsin :)